# How can I check if my installed numpy is compiled with SSE/SSE2 instruction set?

Tags: python, numpy, sse

How can I check if my installed version of numpy is compiled with SSE/SSE2 instruction set? 
I know that some parts of numpy is using BLAS, how to check BLAS too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.show_all()
```

This will print out all of the information about what numpy was compiled against.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as it does not check for any dependency depending on it recursively.

Answer (score 12):

I think that one way is to use objdump on a numpy.so file if you are under linux, and grep for instruction that are specific to sse.

for SSE3 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) :

```
objdump -d  /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/numpy/core/*.so | grep -i MOVDDUP
```

for SSE2 (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_d%27instructions_x86#Instructions_SSE2) :

```
objdump -d  /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/numpy/core/*.so | grep -i ADDPD
```

if you get some results with the grep it means that the binary has been compiled with the SSE flags.

Comment: In my system (derivative of Ubuntu 14.04), those files are `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/*.so` .

Comment: To find your numpy location :  `python3 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)"`

Comment: Checking against a single instruction from an instruction set is not very robust. Moreover, this will match against AVX instructions `VADDPD` and `VMOVDDUP`. I improved your solution in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, find the path of numpy/core .so files:

```
python -c "import numpy, os; print (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__), 'core/*.so'))"
#  Output:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/*.so
```

Then decompile numpy's core to file numpy.asm:

```
objdump -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/*.so > numpy.asm
```

Then find **all** SSE instructions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /\<(ADDPS|ADDSS|ANDNPS|ANDPS|CMPPS|CMPSS|COMISS|CVTPI2PS|CVTPS2PI|CVTSI2SS|CVTSS2S|CVTTPS2PI|CVTTSS2SI|DIVPS|DIVSS|LDMXCSR|MAXPS|MAXSS|MINPS|MINSS|MOVAPS|MOVHLPS|MOVHPS|MOVLHPS|MOVLPS|MOVMSKPS|MOVNTPS|MOVSS|MOVUPS|MULPS|MULSS|ORPS|RCPPS|RCPSS|RSQRTPS|RSQRTSS|SHUFPS|SQRTPS|SQRTSS|STMXCSR|SUBPS|SUBSS|UCOMISS|UNPCKHPS|UNPCKLPS|XORPS|PAVGB|PAVGW|PEXTRW|PINSRW|PMAXSW|PMAXUB|PMINSW|PMINUB|PMOVMSKB|PSADBW|PSHUFW)\>/' numpy.asm
```

Find all SSE2 instructions (except MOVSD and CMPSD, which were first introduced in 80386):

```
gawk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /\<(ADDPD|ADDSD|ANDNPD|ANDPD|CMPPD|COMISD|CVTDQ2PD|CVTDQ2PS|CVTPD2DQ|CVTPD2PI|CVTPD2PS|CVTPI2PD|CVTPS2DQ|CVTPS2PD|CVTSD2SI|CVTSD2SS|CVTSI2SD|CVTSS2SD|CVTTPD2DQ|CVTTPD2PI|CVTPS2DQ|CVTTSD2SI|DIVPD|DIVSD|MAXPD|MAXSD|MINPD|MINSD|MOVAPD|MOVHPD|MOVLPD|MOVMSKPD|MOVUPD|MULPD|MULSD|ORPD|SHUFPD|SQRTPD|SQRTSD|SUBPD|SUBSD|UCOMISD|UNPCKHPD|UNPCKLPD|XORPD|MOVDQ2Q|MOVDQA|MOVDQU|MOVQ2DQ|PADDQ|PMULUDQ|PSHUFHW|PSHUFLW|PSHUFD|PSLLDQ|PSRLDQ|PUNPCKHQDQ|PUNPCKLQDQ)\>/' numpy.asm
```

Find all SSE3 instructions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /\<(ADDSUBPD|ADDSUBPS|HADDPD|HADDPS|HSUBPD|HSUBPS|MOVDDUP|MOVSHDUP|MOVSLDUP|LDDQU|FISTTP)\>/' numpy.asm
```

Find all SSSE3 instructions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /\<(PSIGNW|PSIGND|PSIGNB|PSHUFB|PMULHRSW|PMADDUBSW|PHSUBW|PHSUBSW|PHSUBD|PHADDW|PHADDSW|PHADDD|PALIGNR|PABSW|PABSD|PABSB)\>/' numpy.asm
```

Find all SSE4 instructions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /\<(MPSADBW|PHMINPOSUW|PMULLD|PMULDQ|DPPS|DPPD|BLENDPS|BLENDPD|BLENDVPS|BLENDVPD|PBLENDVB|PBLENDDW|PMINSB|PMAXSB|PMINUW|PMAXUW|PMINUD|PMAXUD|PMINSD|PMAXSD|ROUNDPS|ROUNDSS|ROUNDPD|ROUNDSD|INSERTPS|PINSRB|PINSRD|PINSRQ|EXTRACTPS|PEXTRB|PEXTRD|PEXTRW|PEXTRQ|PMOVSXBW|PMOVZXBW|PMOVSXBD|PMOVZXBD|PMOVSXBQ|PMOVZXBQ|PMOVSXWD|PMOVZXWD|PMOVSXWQ|PMOVZXWQ|PMOVSXDQ|PMOVZXDQ|PTEST|PCMPEQQ|PCMPGTQ|PACKUSDW|PCMPESTRI|PCMPESTRM|PCMPISTRI|PCMPISTRM|CRC32|POPCNT|MOVNTDQA|EXTRQ|INSERTQ|MOVNTSD|MOVNTSS|LZCNT)\>/' numpy.asm
```

Comment: Searching for scalar SSE/SSE2 instructions is not very interesting.  It's somewhat better than x87, but the real gains come from SIMD `addps`, not scalar `addss`.    And BTW, to check for AVX, search for `%ymm` to find uses of 256-bit vector registers.

Comment: Also, why gawk instead of `egrep -i`, or `fgrep` with a list of patterns from a file?  And BTW, `objdump -d` always uses lower-case mnemonics.

Comment: @PeterCordes, no special reason. You can use other tools. Good to know about objdump.

Comment: use `otool -tv` instead of `objdump -d` on macOS